# $q$-analogs confusion in some steps

Tags: combinatorics, q-analogs

I am understanding the proof of the general version of the **Jacobi triple product**, that is $$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+xq^{2k-2})=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{k(k-1)}}{(q^2)_k}x^k$$

In the proof to this identity, there is this one step where it goes;

$$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(-1)^l \frac{q^{l^2+l+2kl}}{(q^2)_l}-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{k^2}x^k\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(-1)^l \frac{q^{l^2+l+2kl}}{(q^2)_l}=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-q)^lq^{(k+l)^2}}{(q^2)_l}x^k$$

Can anyone help me with the understanding of this part, if I just understand this part, then I am nearly done with understanding the whole proof.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: O yes for the source its https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/blog.nus.edu.sg/dist/2/3912/files/2014/10/Chapter9-20ycqjr.pdf on page 7 of the pdf .

Comment: Author and title? Anyway, it looks like a misprint to me. The minus sign in the first line should be an equals sign, and the LHS on the first line should be the LHS of (9.16).  The whole thing appears to be a copy-and-paste blunder.

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification, I will try to see with this typo in hand whether I can go ahead and understand the final steps of the proof.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Ok so I am stuck again in the same pdf file page 5, I do not understand why $A(x)B(x)$ is the coefficient of the term $x^k$  in the equation $(9.11)$, could you please help me understand this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get 
$$\sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-q)^lq^{(k+l)^2}}{(q^2)_l}x^k
=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty
\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^l \frac{q^{k^2+2kl+l^2+l}}{(q^2)_l}x^k
=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty q^{k^2}x^k
\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^l \frac{q^{l^2+l+2kl}}{(q^2)_l}$$
which **isn't** what you have on the left, but maybe should be?

Comment: Which is why I am confused, because it doesnt seem to make sense no matter how many times i try to fiddle around with it.